# How to get indexes of items greater or less than each item in a NumPy array without using a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, decision-tree

I am writing a Decision Tree algorithm from scratch, right now I'm trying to split the data into groups where each group contains values that are greater or equal or less than each value in a NumPy array containing the values of a continuous DataFrame column, and get the mean of the targets of those splits.
My code so far:

```
for i in range(len(columns)):
    col = columns[i]
    # cont - list of continous columns in my DataFrame
    if col in cont:
        values  = xs[col].values
        targets = y.values
        for j in range(len(values)):
            value = values[j]
            greater_idx = np.where(values >= value)[0]
            less_idx    = np.where(values <  value)[0]
            targets_greater = targets[greater_idx].sum()
            targets_less    = targets[less_idx]   .sum()
        print(targets_greater/(j+1))
        print(targets_less   /(j+1))
```

The xs DataFrame is of length almost 400k, so the loop is really slow, it kills my Jupyter Notebook kernel every time. I know there should be a way to completely get rid of that loop, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having a vectorized way of performing your comparison, there is a lot of room for algorithmic improvement:

1. Get the sorted indices for `xs[col].values` using `np.argsort` (`sorted_idxs`).
2. Using `np.insert(np.cumsum(targets[sorted_idxs]), 0, 0)[:-1]` gets you a vector of `target_less` for every value in `xs[col].values`.
3. `target_less[0]` (0) is the `target_less`-value for the lowest element in `xs[col].values` - to "unsort" `target_less` you can use `unsort_idx = np.argsort(sorted_idxs)` and `target_less[unsort_idx]`.

Now you have all `target_less`-values for all your values in the array (`target_greater` is of course easily obtained through `targets.sum() - target_less`).

Edit:

Here is code to go along with the suggestion:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

xs = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10000))
y = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=10000))

sorted_idxs = np.argsort(xs[0].values)
sorted_values = xs[0].values[sorted_idxs]
sorted_targets = y.values[sorted_idxs]
sorted_targets_less = np.insert(np.cumsum(sorted_targets), 0, 0)[:-1]

unsorted_idxs = np.argsort(sorted_idxs)
targets_less = sorted_targets_less[unsorted_idxs]

for i, target_less_value in enumerate(targets_less):
    assert target_less_value == y.values[np.where(xs.values < xs.values[i])[0]].sum()
```

One word of warning: Above assumes a strictly distinct set of values in xs.values. If you have repeated values, then you need to adjust the part that does the cumulative sum.